# Encontrar posições corretas na Matriz

Tags: c++

Estou tendo dificuldades com este raciocínio. Tenho uma matriz `4x4`. Devo preenchê-la com 0 e 1, desde que o número 1 apareça duas vezes em cada linha e em cada coluna, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
1   1   0   0       
1   0   0   1       
0   0   1   1       
0   1   1   0
```

Mas a situação abaixo pode ocorrer. Aí eu teria que que mover o "1" de `(2,3)` para `(4,2)` que voltará a ficar como no exemplo acima.

```
1   1   0   0       
1   0   1   1       
0   0   1   1       
0   0   1   0
```

Se eu somar as linhas e colunas, posso identificar qual linha e coluna está errada, mas não consigo fazer meu programa identificar a posição exata.

Eu preciso dar um retorno do tipo "mover de `(2,3)` para `(4,2)`".
Como meu programa pode encontrar as posições exatas?

Comment: Como está seu código atual? Minha sugestão - assumindo que o número de 0s e 1s está correto - é procurar pela linha e pela coluna com mais 1s, e mover essa posição para a linha e a coluna com mais 0s. Se a soma das linhas estiver correta mas a das colunas não (ou vice-versa), mova um `1` na própria linha, da coluna com mais pra coluna com menos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Se eu somar as linhas e colunas, posso identificar qual linha e coluna
>   está errada, mas não consigo fazer meu programa identificar a posição
>   exata.

R: consegue sim, a lógica é realmente somar cada linha e coluna, se a soma for maior que dois(2) você saberá qual a posição da linha,coluna com valores a mais ou seja onde tem mais 1's do que deveria, você deverá mover para a posição onde a soma for menor que dois(2) isso te diz exatamente onde está faltando número 1, seguindo seu exemplo a lógica seria a seguinte:

Para esta matriz:

```
1   1   0   0       
1   0   1   1       
0   0   1   1       
0   0   1   0
```

**Vamos começar somando todas as linhas primeiro !**

Some a primeira linha da Matriz :

```
1   1   0   0  ==> soma == 2 (OK)
```

Some a segunda linha da Matriz :

```
1   0   1   1  ==> soma == 3 (segunda linha da matriz com problema tem número a mais) > 2
```

Terceira linha da Matriz :

```
0   0   1   1  ==> soma == 2 (OK)
```

Quarta linha da Matriz:

```
0   0   1   0  ==> soma ==  1 (quarta linha da matriz com problema tem número a menos) <2
```

**Hora de somar as colunas:**

Primeira coluna:

```
1        
1          ==> soma == 2 (OK)
0          
0
```

Segunda coluna:

```
1        
0        ==> soma == 1 (problema) < 2
0       
0
```

Terceira coluna:

```
0        
1        ==> soma == 3 (problema) > 2
1         
1
```

Quarta coluna:

```
0       
1       ==> soma == 2 (OK)
1       
0
```

Agora observe qual linha e coluna possue soma maior que dois (>2), vai ser exatamente a segunda linha e terceira coluna posição `(2,3)` você acaba de encontrar as posições com valores errados onde se tem mais 1's do que deveria ter, OK agora para encontrar para qual posição mover observe qual é a posição cujo valor é menor que dois (<2) você vai notar que será a quarta linha e segunda coluna `(4,2)`, ai está uma maneira lógica de se chegar ao resultado!

Comment: Isso! Ficar mexendo com tanta matriz me confunde as vezes, mas depois dessa explicação ficou mais claro e consegui bolar um código aqui. Obrigado o/